# NGINX - setting proxy_connect_timeout at location level

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I run NGINX as reverse proxy to my node.js app (with socket.io). Since node.js was disconnecting the socket.io connection because of idle timeout, after research I found setting NGINX's proxy_connect_timeout to a large value works.

But I want to set this only for /socket.io/ location. When I do as below, **I get 404 for this location and socket.io cannot connect.**

Snippet of my config below.

```
    location ~ ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets)/  {
        root    D:/myapp/public/;
    }

    location /socket.io/  {
      proxy_read_timeout 8h;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7710;
    }
```

Comment: Put this `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7710;` in the socket.io location block.

Comment: Location blocks are not 'combined' only one is ever used.

Comment: @JamesJJ is there any downside to setting proxy_read_timeout at the server level instead of location level? (with regards to resources hogging etc?)